# AWS SAM generate event with pictures as data

Tags: aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I would like to build an API where two pictures are being processed. One picture is a challenge and the other one is the solution. So they are a only being useful as a pair.

How can I create with `sam local generate event` an example event for my API where I POST those two pictures against my API?